# Radio Buttons for a custom dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I  have a custom dialog with radio buttons , I need to listen for change (in case any )  from the dialog opened and set text from that. Since I have done that using java , I dont know how to use onCheckedChangedListener. How do I do that . I am new to android and I dont know much .Please help me.

```
public class Availability extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ToggleButton override;
    TextView status;
    Button Overridestatus;
    CharSequence [] choice = {"RemoteOffice","Office","Personel mobile","Home","Mobile","Temporary","Do not Disturb","Working Remotely","Non work day","Work Day"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.availability);
        override = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbOver);
        override.setOnClickListener(this);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvstatus);
        Overridestatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstatus);
        Overridestatus.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.tbOver:

            if (override.isChecked()) {

                status.setText("Override");
                Overridestatus.setText("Personal Mobile");

            } else {
                status.setText("Currently");
                Overridestatus.setText("Use Schedule - Do Not Disturb");

            }
            break;

        case R.id.bstatus:

            {
                if (override.isChecked()){
                showDialog(0);
                }
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (id) {
        case 0:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Select System Server");
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_btn_round_more_normal);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent menu = new Intent(Availability.this,MenuScreen.class);
                            startActivity(menu);

                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(choice, -1,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

            builder.create();
            builder.show();
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the states of the radio buttons and save them in your local variables for further use.

Please refer the excellent developers guide here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Read through it once and you'll figure out how to extract and save the states of various elements in your custom dialogs.

Comment: could you also take a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908902/custom-dialog-date-and-time-picker-with-radio-buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

```
public class Availability extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnCheckedChangeListener {
    ....
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    switch(group.getId())
    {
    }
}
```

You can put the RadioButtons in a RadioGroup.

Comment: That is fine , but my radio buttons show up when I open a custom dialog and I need to something after that.(I also have radio buttons do not confuse with them]

Comment: Don't you have an Activity for your custom dialog?