# Custom dialog with a Timepicker

Tags: android, android-widget

I am starting a new activity from a main activity . I need to display a Time Pickerdialog when a radio button on the main activity is clicked .i am getting an error when i click on the radio button which is suppose to show me the dialog.

CODE

```
import java.util.Calendar; 
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class Tilldate extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }

}
```

LOGCAT

```
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.avst.callxpressmobile/com.example.avst.callxpressmobile.Tilldate}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.avst.callxpressmobile.Tilldate cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.avst.callxpressmobile.Tilldate cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
10-16 13:01:37.539: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):     ... 11 more
```

For my main activity please have a look at

[Number of Custom Dialogs (Date and Time Picker) with relation to Radio Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908902/custom-dialog-date-and-time-picker-with-radio-buttons)

Comment: Just to reiterate what's in the LogCat: `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` ?

Comment: @Tim Please have a look at my new Logcat

Comment: I think you have some confusion between `Activity` and `Fragment`. `Tilldate` is a fragment, not an activity. Unfortunately I am not well-versed enough in fragments to be able to help, but it seems that you cannot claim that your fragment is an Activity.

Comment: @Tim , how do I solve it ?i need it for my  previous activity . Any Suggestions , ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not an activity remove Tilldate from the AndroidManifest.xml and then assuming you are calling startActivity ,
use

```
  DialogFragment dialog = new Tilldate();
```

> <strike>dialog .show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");</strike>

```
  dialog .show(getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "dialog");
```

Instead of startActivity

If you need a custom dialog, extend TimePickerDialog.

Comment: can you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908902/number-of-custom-dialogs-date-and-time-picker-with-relation-to-radio-buttons

Comment: well in the example, they are calling the dialog, whereas you have created a dialogFragment. if you want a custom timepickerdialog extend Tilldate with TimePickerDialog rather than dialogfragment

Comment: **show** is giving an error - `The method show(FragmentManager, String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentManager, String)`

Comment: All I need is a custom dialog when I change the radio buttons . Can You please help me how to do it??

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908902/number-of-custom-dialogs-date-and-time-picker-with-relation-to-radio-buttons)

Comment: Fragments may be too complex for me . Is ther any way I can Implement it??

Comment: instead of  extends DialogFragment use extends TimePIckerDialog

Comment: I m seriously lost :( Is there anything other than this  can do ?? My main aim is to create three custom dialog as shown in the link (in comments)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18154/discussion-between-new2android-and-nandeesh)